# STS / Grails, Error initializing resources: The alias mapping '/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1

Tags: spring, grails, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I am working with my colleagues on our first Grails web app project. From the begining I am struggling with some strange issue. I am using Spring Tool Suite, Java JDK 1.7.0_45 and grails 2.2.4.

I simply import existing project to STS and then Run-As -> Grails Command (run-app) and I got this error instead of working app(my colleagues doesnt have this error but use the same existing project):

```
| Loading Grails 2.2.4
| Configuring classpath.
| Environment set to development.....
| Packaging Grails application.....
| Running Grails application
| Error 2013-11-18 12:03:39,505 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error initializing resources: The alias mapping '/plugins/famfamfam-1.0.1=C:\Users\Sebastian\(some path)\ProjectName\target\plugins\famfamfam-1.0.1\.\web-app' is not valid
| Error 2013-11-18 12:03:39,585 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error getConfigured
| Error 2013-11-18 12:03:39,586 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/ProjectName] startup failed due to previous errors
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/ProjectName
```

Looking forward for any help!

Comment: Try removing the `target` folder and refreshing dependencies before running your application.

Comment: Tried several times before. Didnt help at all. Plugin is successfully installed and the same error occurs.

One thing bother me, the last part of the path: '...plugins\famfamfam-1.0.1\.\web-app' - I dont know why there is '\.\' part before web-app. What does it mean? In the folder structure 'famfamfam-1.0.1' folder is just a parent of a 'web-app' folder...